# Estimate parameter of Frank Copula

Tags: r, parameters, statistics, curve-fitting, estimation

I'm analyzing some bivariate data with copulas. In order to simulate some copulas I need to estimate the corresponding parameters.

For example:

```
gumbel.fit<-fit.AC(Udata, "gumbel")
gumbel.parameter<-gumbel.fit$fit$par
```

or

```
clayton.fit<-fit.AC(Udata, "clayton")
clayton.parameter<-clayton.fit$fit$par
```

But this can't be applied to Frank copula, therefor I wonder how to estimate the paramter?

- Are there any function in r that allows me to do this?
- The only way to do this is programming the maximum likelihood?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the CDVine package `BiCopEst(u1,u2,5,method="mle")`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the `R` package `copula` which provides various estimators including detailed examples (specifically, numerically stable MLE).

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate any copula parameter using for example "CDvine" package in R. In this case you can select any available method. There is a "Tau" estimation method or the pseudo-observation maximum likelihood method. Currently, to my best of knowledge, there are no further estimation methods available in the R.